# Show div after reload if check box is checked

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying show and hide a div if checked. I have it working but if i reload the page and one of the check boxes is checked the div with the corresponding data attr wont show. I think this maybe due to the toogleClass('hidden') and i am not checking if checked show the corresponding div with the correct data attr.

-Thanks for all the help

**html input**

```
<div class="input string optional additional_user_info_species_selection field_with_hint boolean">
<label class="string optional" for="additional_user_info_species_selection">Do you own or care for any of these species on your farm or ranch?</label>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input name="additional_user_info[has_cattle]" type="hidden" value="0">
    <input data-toggle-fields=".cattle-fields" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="additional_user_info[has_cattle]" id="additional_user_info_has_cattle">
    <label for="additional_user_info_has_cattle">Cattle</label>
</div>
```

**html show if checked if reload**

```
<div class="input integer optional additional_user_info_beef_cows_amt field_with_errors field_with_hint cattle-fields hidden">
<label class="integer optional" for="additional_user_info_beef_cows_amt">What is your annual maintained inventory of beef cows?</label>
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="additional_user_info[beef_cows_amt]" id="additional_user_info_beef_cows_amt">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span>Beef Cows</span>
    </div>
</div>
<span class="hint">If none, please enter '0'</span><span class="error">can't be blank</span>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.additional_user_info_species_selection input').change(function(){
        var target = $(this).data('toggle-fields');
        $(target).toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Comment: When you say reload, do you mean a full page reload? In that case you will have to use localStorage/cookies to keep track of your data.

Comment: Well say one of the check boxes was already checked when you went to the page. Show the div equal to the data attr of the input. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over all the `.additional_user_info_species_selection` **checked checkboxes** of your page, then show (*or unhide*) the corresponding div.

**Using javascript (and a bit of jQuery)**

```
$('.additional_user_info_species_selection input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    document.querySelector(this.dataset.toggleFields).classList.remove('hidden');
});
```

**Using jQuery**

```
$('.additional_user_info_species_selection input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    $($(this).data('toggle-fields')).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

---

**Final javascript** (*with the javascript version*)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.additional_user_info_species_selection input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        document.querySelector(this.dataset.toggleFields).classList.remove('hidden');
    });

    $('.additional_user_info_species_selection input').change(function() {
        var target = $(this).data('toggle-fields');
        $(target).toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you revisit the page and we assume the checkbox is checked because of for example a previous form post you have to check this in your $(document).ready();

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// see if the checkbox is already checked when arriving on the page
if($('.additional_user_info_species_selection input').is(':checked')){
   // do logic here to show the corresponding div
}
else{
   // do logic here to hide the corresponding div
}


$('.additional_user_info_species_selection input').change(function(){
    var target = $(this).data('toggle-fields');
    $(target).toggleClass('hidden');
});
});
```

This code can be improved but I hope you understand the idea of this solution.